# Data structure for a navigational sequence

Tags: data-structures, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a Silverlight LOB application that has a page that will need to be visited 4 times before moving on to the next page.  I want a data structure to hold a marker to the point in that sequence.  I might render a display to show where you are like this: o---●---o---o

I tried an enum, but I need to associate each point with small int value that is then used to locate files via HTTP.  This seems so simple but if I start putting if blocks and magic variable values everywhere that is messy, so I wanted to see what people here had to say.

Comment: Your question is too specific. Can you give a more generalized question ? Like What exactly is your need. What is the block that lies in your way?

Comment: People who are using WCF RIA Services will get it, I think.  I have created a page under that framework, but I want to reuse it several times.  I am looking for a way to track that reuse so that after 4 times I can move on.